# How to encrypt/secure single columns ins SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2016, security, encryption

I would like to secure some columns in my data warehouse. People who are generally allowed to query the database should get returned the columns but encoded. For example:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID FROM PERSON

PERSON_ID
-----------
yba986SDOAH
```

When some else who has the key queries in some way the table/columns then he/she should get the correct value.

Which options do i have in SQL Server > 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not an expert, I will suggest reading the following article on the c-sharp corner:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-column-level-encryption-decryption-in-sql-server-2016/

This details the process fairly well and has some working examples posted in a way that i feel might suit your application.